# How to process array in sequence async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, shopify-api-node

I'm trying to make a table with Shopify orders and links to the pictures. But have an issue with the async loop. Each time I run the code orders appear in the console in the wrong sequence, like 998, 996, 1000... Should be 1000, 999, 998...
I tried to add the async keyword in different places and also wrap a function in settimeout function and many many more, but no luck.
How to make orders list in the right sequence?
Thank you in advance.

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('./keys.json');
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');
const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
);
const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: 'name.myshopify.com',
  apiKey: 'key',
  password: 'pas'
});
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: client});
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: client});

function getLink(){
    client.authorize(()=> gsrun());
}

async function runDrive(ord, sku){
    const resDrive = await drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 1,
    q: `name contains "sku"`,
    spaces: 'drive',
    });
    const files = resDrive.data.files;
    let link;
    if (files.length) {
            link = `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${files[0].id}/view`;
    } else {
    // console.log('No files found.');
    link = 'No files found.';
    }
    console.log([ord, sku, link])
}

async function gsrun(){
    // Shopify - Get orders list
    let orders = await shopify.order.list({ limit: 7 });
    ordersArray = orders.forEach(ord => {
        skuArray = ord.line_items.forEach(async (item) => {
            // Drive - Search for SKUs
            runDrive(ord.order_number, item.sku)
        })
    })
}
getLink()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `forEach` the order of asynchronous execution is not sequential. You can try to use `for of` instead of `forEach` in `gsrun` function:

```
async function gsrun(){
  // Shopify - Get orders list
  let orders = await shopify.order.list({ limit: 7 });
  for (const ord of orders) {
    for (const item of ord.line_items) {
      await runDrive(ord.order_number, item.sku)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps me!